# dev/sd4: clean, 104708/243100 blocks

Tags: shutdown

Ubuntu 16.04, has a problem with /dev/sd4 and fails to turn off the computer. So i have to turn it off manually.

When I turn the computer off the message `dev/sd4: clean, 104708/243100 blocks`

and after 5 minutes if I do not turn off a few more lines are written. But it still refuses to turn off.

How can I solve this problem so that the computer turns off quickly?

I noticed that by command `systemctl poweroff` everything is OK. but I don't want to use terminal and command every time.

Comment: Please tell us those additional lines that appear later. And I also doubt you mean `/dev/sd4` as that should not exist. Do you mean `/dev/sda4` instead?

Comment: for example: `kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup`

Comment: I don't know what happens but it does not shut down.

Comment: Please include all those other messages you see when waiting for it to shut down for a longer time. They are important to find out what happened. You can also examine `/var/log/syslog` and upload the important parts of it about events around your last failed shutdown.